# How to manually force reload of files from an RPM package?

Tags: fedora, rpm, chroot

After a Fedora distro upgrade (27->28) with `dnf`, I tried to manually resolve conflicts between package versions (needed to keep older OS versions functional; effective OS version is selected at boot time in GRUB2 menu).

`dnf` security checks prevented the removal of conflicting packages and I used `rpm -e xxx --force` to do that. I inadvertently removed glibc and the PC immediately errored out.

I want to avoid rebuilding my computer from scratch because:

1. I don't exactly remember all applications I installed years ago (they were automatically upgraded by dnf system-upgrade), and
2. there would be a huge configuration work in /etc to restore custom settings for my network environment plus the servers on the machine.

Using a rescue disk, I could boot and examine the hard disk. Everything seems relatively "clean". Files from glibc package are simply missing.

I could not complete `chroot` to the former root (in order to run `rpm -i glibc`) because `chroot` tries to launch `/bin/bash` which is missing.

**Is there a way to tell rpm to do its usual job but to install files in, say, `/mnt/hard_disk/` instead of `/`?**

I'll take care afterwards of package database consistency and integrity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chroot` can take a command to run to this might work:

```
chroot /mnt/hard_disk rpm -i glibc*.rpm
```

Also, `rpm` has the `--root` option so this is another option:

```
rpm -i --root /mnt/hard_disk glibc*.rpm
```

Comment: `chroot … rpm …` doesn't work because `bash` is needed to launch command and it was erased. I tried `/bin/rpm` (where I found rpm) or `bin/rpm` to no avail.

`rpm -i --root …` is the right solution. PC can reboot now.

Comment: Everything back to normal. Conflicts resolved. Apparently they were cause by package(s) missing in the new repo (not updated yet?) causing dnf system upgrade to fail, leaving configuration in a mixed state.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this, though it doesn't use the `rpm` command. You'll need to have the `rpm2cpio` binary available, and then you simply do:

```
# cd /mnt/hard_disk
# rpm2cpio <rpmfile> | cpio -idmv
```

As you mentioned, you'll need to deal with RPMDB integrity issues afterwards, but that will get the files into place for you. There are numerous web pages with information and more details about this available through a simple google search, one of them is https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/13/inspect-extract-contents-rpm-packages/.

Comment: Thanks @John, I'll have a try. A small difficulty: the rescue disk is a DVD-ROM and I can't add utilitities. In particular, I can't run `rpm -i rpm2cpio` on it. Since package `rpm2cpio` seems to spawn files in numerous locations, how do I solve that? Also the suggested command(s) do not run the pre- & post-scripts in the rpm.

Comment: Can't you? Most rescue environments I've seen are built on a ramdisk-based root filesystem.

Comment: The suggested `rpm2cpio <rpm> | cpio -idmv` will extract relative to the current directory, so if you are in `/mnt/hard_disk` when executing that, any files in the RPM that would normally extract to `/lib` will go to `/mnt/hard_disk/lib` instead. The aim is to restore the essential files of glibc and the dynamic loader first, as a quick fix. Once you can successfully run `chroot /mnt/hard_disk bash`, you will be able to use `rpm --reinstall glibc-*.rpm` to achieve a "proper" reinstallation - but to run `rpm`, glibc and the dynamic loader must be in place.

Comment: @ajlittoz if you don't have rpm2cpio, you can use script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986787/2600099) instead

Comment: @Mark Wagner's solution is better since it uses `rpm` without tweak. Thanks anyway.